# Is there any option to set style for my required fields in community builder for joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

1. I have installed Community Builder 1.8.1 and using it in my Joomla2.5.7.
2. Its being installed perfectly and working nice.
3. But,i want my fields to display in bold when i set "Required ?:" to "Yes".
4. I have searched for it,but all in vain.
5. Is there any way to hack the codes or there any option for it in the component.
6. Even a small tip is very useful for me.I am very new to Joomla.

Answer (score 1):

In the stylesheet for community builder, look for this,

```
cbFieldIconsLabels {

}
```

and add the following:

```
font-weight: bold;
```

Comment: Its not there in my template.css of CB.Also,i tried to add this.But,nothing happened.Need only "required" fields to be in bold.

Comment: Need my Labels of textboxes being set as "required" to be in bold.Is this possible for community builder's registration form